# TypeError at /register/new_reg/ register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: django, sqlite

i was just  checking this  code  please help me in finding this error

```
   def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        register(name=name,phone=phone).save()

    return render(request, 'reg.html')

  
models
-------

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.



class register(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

please  resolve this  issue
please  help me to  find  whats  wrong  with it
and  thanks  in  advance

Comment: Your model's name and view method's name are same(`register`). Change one of them to something else.

Answer (score 1):

`name` cannot be directly used to the request body of `drive_service.files().list()`. If you want to retrieve files which have the filename of hello, modify from `name = 'hello'` to `q='name = \'hello\'`'. If you want to retrieve files which include hello in the filename, modify from `name = 'hello'` to `q='name` contains 'hello''. If you want to retrieve files which include hello in the contents, modify from name = 'hello' to `q='fullText` contains `\'"hello"\'`'. The document of about q is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-shareddrives)